# What's the purpose of "main" in \setmainfont?

Tags: fontspec, roman

In the following MCE, the default font is sans serif, as it is by default the case e.g. with the `beamer` class. And the "main" font (declared by `\setmainfont`) is not the same as the "default" ("normal") one, but rather is the "roman" font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont{Punk Nova}[Color=red]
\setsansfont{QTAgateType}
\setmonofont{QTArabian}[Color=blue]

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Default:] Test
\item[Roman:] \textrm{Test}
\item[Sans serif:] \textsf{Test}
\item[Monospace:] \texttt{Test}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

So:

- What is the purpose of "main" in `\setmainfont`?
- Isn't the purpose of `\setmainfont` rather to declare the roman font and, if so, why isn't this command rather called `\setromanfont`?

Comment: I'm setting a wedding invitation, and I want it to be Fraktur.  `\setromanfont` would make absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 5):

It sets the default font (but only until you reset it)

If you modify your eaxmple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\normalfont \showthe\font
\setmainfont{Punk Nova}[Color=red]
\normalfont \showthe\font
\setsansfont{QTAgateType}
\setmonofont{QTArabian}[Color=blue]

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}


\item[Default:] Test
\item[Roman:] \textrm{Test}
\item[Sans serif:] \textsf{Test}

\item[Monospace:] \texttt{Test}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

You get

```
> \TU/lmr/m/n/10 .
<recently read> \font 
      
l.5 \normalfont \showthe\font
```

The default font is still latin modern roman at this point

Then you get

```
> \TU/PunkNova(0)/m/n/10 .
<recently read> \font 
      
l.7 \normalfont \showthe\font
```

showing the effect of `\setmainfont`

Then you do

```
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

which will make the default font pick up whatever you have specified for Sans serif. (beamer does something similar at begin document as well)

Comment: OK but don't you think it would have been less confusing to name this command `\setromanfont`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé that _would_ be confusing, if the font you use isn't Roman for example It does literally what it says it sets the default font, if you redefine \rmfamily or \familydefault afterwards you would see the same thing. the issue isn't related to sans serif or beamer

Comment: @DenisBitouzé In some older versions of `fontspec`, it was `\setromanfont`. You’d have to ask Will Robertson why he named the commands that way. But, to me `\setmainfont` doesn’t imply “Set the main font, and also prevent authors from changing it.”

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That would *not* be more confusing than e.g. `\setsansfont` if the font you use isn't sans serif, for example `\setsansfont{KpRoman}`.